# How to use isalnum with 2d array

Tags: c

```
char dict[N][M];

for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    do
    {
        printf("enter word at position: %d\n", i);    
        gets(dict[i]);
        printf("you entered %s\n", dict[i]);    

        if(isalnum(dict[i]))
        {
            printf("error\n");
        }
    }while (isalnum(dict[i]));    
}
```

Hello I'm new to C and I want to do validation with `isalnum` but with a 2d array
for example if `dict[0][80]` is non alphanumeric the user enter again.

Thanks

Comment: do not use `gets` function, it was already deprecated in the previous C standard and the function was removed in the current C standard

Comment: traverse the dict[i] and check for each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler should print a warning similar to this when you try to compile your code:

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘isalnum’ makes integer from pointer without a cast.

This warning is a sign that the code isn't doing what you want, and here's why.  The signature of the "isalnum" function is `int isalnum(int c)` which means it takes an integer (i.e. character) argument; however, you're calling it with the argument `dict[i]`, which is a `char *` (a pointer to a character, e.g. a string).

I'm guessing what you want to do is check that each character in the string is alphabetic or numeric.  Try replacing your call to "isalnum" with your own function like so:

```c
/* Returns true iff each character of "s" is alphabetic or numeric. */
int str_isalnum(char * s) {
  int i=0, len=strlen(s);
  for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (!isalnum(s[i])) return 0; /* false */
  }
  return 1; /* true */
}

/* ... */
  printf("you entered %s\n", dict[i]);    
  if (!str_isalnum(dict[i])) {
    printf("error\n");
  }
} while (!str_isalnum(dict[i]));
```